# Getting Asana Task sort order via API

Tags: asana

I am trying to get the sort order associated with of within a project.  I don't see a field with info in it.  When I get the tasks can I assume that order the tasks are in the json is the sort order in the Project?  It looks like it that is the case, I just would like confirmation.

Thanks
Randy

Answer (score 0):

When we return the tasks associated with a project we return them in "project priority" order - as in, the order they've been put into manually. If you change the view in the app (say, to sort by hearted) they'll still be in the manual order when fetched via the API.